# How can I replace elemts of a list with other elements

Tags: python, list, replace

I have two lists:

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
b = [120, 131, 152, 143]
```

i would like to replace "1" from the list 'a' with the elements of the list 'b', the order matters. I would like to have something like this

```
c = [120, 131, 0, 152, 0, 0, 143]
```

Comment: Hi @Christian , Please show what you're tried so far ?

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach by converting `b` to a iterable object using `iter()`.

**Ex:**

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] 
b = iter([120, 131, 152, 143])

print([next(b) if val == 1 else val for val in a])
```

**Output:**

```
[120, 131, 0, 152, 0, 0, 143]
```

Answer (score 2):

A more "traditional" approach, with a simple loop:

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
b = [120, 131, 152, 143]
ans = []
i, j = 0, 0

while i < len(a):
    if a[i] == 1:
        ans.append(b[j])
        j += 1
    else:
        ans.append(0)
    i += 1

ans
=> [120, 131, 0, 152, 0, 0, 143]
```